# URL Scheme shortcuts://create-shortcut?name=YourShortcutName&url=YOUR_URL_ENCODED_CONTENT"

Tags: swift, ios-shortcut

I am trying to find out how I can automatically create a shortcut like this. Of course the user interaction to save this shortcut is recommend.

```
if let createShortcutURL = URL(string: "shortcuts://create-shortcut?name=YourShortcutName&url=YOUR_URL_ENCODED_CONTENT") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(createShortcutURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

It just opens the window in the shortcut app to create a new "shortcut".

Has anyone already had experience in this context?

Comment: You have mentioned many layers of technology. Can you describe a use case? The code you have looks like it might be trying to tell Apple's Shortcuts.app to open and do something.

Comment: @ben Yes i try to create a shortcut with the name YourShortName URL to import Shortcut file from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Apple has not documented programatic creation of a shortcut inside Shortcut.app using a `shortcut://` URL

Looking at the documentation [Open and create a shortcut using a URL scheme on iPhone or iPad - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/open-create-and-run-a-shortcut-apda283236d7/ios#:%7E:text=Open%20a%20specific%20shortcut%20using,shortcut%20in%20the%20name%20parameter.)

> Open the URL shortcuts://create-shortcut to jump to the shortcut editor and to create a new shortcut.

> Open a URL with the following structure: shortcuts://open-shortcut?name=[name], and provide the name of the shortcut in the name parameter.

The documentation does not show `?name=` available for `create-shortcut`